# Database Table Relationships

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

Here is my context, in our organization we conduct Marital Relationship Trainings, so I am working on a database to capture information on these trainings and participant information.

Training participants are people with extra marital relationships and polygamous marriages.
So here comes John Doe at the training with partner 1 and partner 2, which counts as as 3 participants in the participants table.

So my issue here, is to relate John Doe's participant_id to his other two partners' participants_id that is also stored in the participants table, as Johnny's other two partners are also considered as participants.

Here my tables I created so far:

1. participants (pid,fname, lname, etc..)
2. prelationship (rid, pid,partnerid, etc..)
3. ptrainingattendance (tid, pid, startdate, endate, ttid)
4. traingtype (ttid,training_details, etc...)

So the 'prelationship' table contains a pid foreign key to 'participants' pid field. And not sure if I should link partnerid also to the pid in participants table.

I know it can be done that way, but is this way not violating the table normalization rules and will this not create any problems in terms of MySql querying of records as more participants data is entered in the participants table? Or perhaps there is an easy solution out there to ease my headache.

Other things to consider:

- Participants are allowed one training each.
- Participant_1 can have multiple partners, who's partners can also have others partners regarded as participants.

Any help is very much appreciated...

Extra notes:
just an update on this question...I been reading this [human app relations](http://allenbrowne.com/AppHuman.html), Allen brown has done something on this topic, maybe I should rethink the whole database structure

Thanks

Comment: I think that the easiest solution is to just store pairs of partners in a table: partner1_id, partner2_id. If I understood you correctly that's what you did in the second table. I don't think you need to complicate this any further.

Comment: Thanks tofig, yes the table 'prelationship' actually addresses this.